# How to generate mesh and plot 3d surface in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyvista

I have 6 corner points coordinate of 3d surface like Figure 1. I want to generate and plot 3d surface like Figure 2. I need to find the distance of midpoint of each meshed area from the origin.
[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqU41.png)

[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXuSJ.png)

Please suggest me, which module will be better for meshing and also for plotting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [vedo](https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter):

```py
from vedo import *

pts = [(-5.795555, -4, 1.55291), (-4.829629, -2, 1.294095),
       (-5.795555, 1, 1.552914), (-5.536736, -4, 2.51884),
       (-4.57081, -2, 2.260021), (-5.536736,  1, 2.51884)]

faces = [(0,3,4,1), (1,4,5,2)]

mesh = Mesh([pts, faces]).color('red').alpha(0.3).lineWidth(2)
labels = [Text(i, pos=pts[i], s=.2, c='k') for i in range(len(pts))]

show(mesh, labels)
```

[image: script result]

Answer (score 1):

[PyVista](https://docs.pyvista.org) and `vtkplotter` are very similar and both are built on top of VTK but have pretty different APIs/design choices. For your use, either would be great! Here is the equivalent with PyVista for completeness.

Typically with simple geometries like this, Matplotlib, PyVista, or `vtkplotter` would all do well. If you start to create more sophisticated meshes and 3D scenes, then that's where PyVista and `vtkplotter` will excel as they are built for 3D while MPL is really awesome at 2D.

PyVista will especially excel at data management if you start making complex meshes.... shameless plug ;)

```py
import pyvista as pv
import numpy as np

# Define the nodes
pts = np.array([(-5.795555, -4, 1.55291), (-4.829629, -2, 1.294095),
       (-5.795555, 1, 1.552914), (-5.536736, -4, 2.51884),
       (-4.57081, -2, 2.260021), (-5.536736,  1, 2.51884)])
# Define the quads
faces = np.array([(4,0,3,4,1), (4,1,4,5,2)])

# Instantiate a mesh
mesh = pv.PolyData(pts, faces)

# Create a plotting window and display!
p = pv.Plotter()

# Add the mesh and some labels
p.add_mesh(mesh, show_edges=True)
p.add_point_labels(mesh.points, ["%d"%i for i in range(mesh.n_points)])

# A pretty view position
p.camera_position = [(-11.352247399703748, -3.421477319390501, 9.827830270231935),
 (-5.1831825, -1.5, 1.9064675),
 (-0.48313206526616853, 0.8593146723923926, -0.16781448484204659)]

# Render it!
p.show()
```

[image]